# Authorization header does not have valid access token in paypal using rest api

Tags: rest, paypal

sir,
i need help  in this topic what i am doing is i try to get the transaction details using paymentid using `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token` this by passwing user name and password as argument in post man but unable to get the valid request it says that

```
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Authorization header does not have valid access token"}
```

i there any way that i cam get the transaction history of a transaction available please guide me
is there any API call available there

Answer (score 0):

The PayPal REST API does not use a username and password for authentication.

First, a client ID and secret are used to obtain an access_token which will be valid for up to 9 hours. These values an be passed as the "username" and "password" fields of HTTP Basic Authentication, if that is what you are referring to -- which means they will be concatenated with a colon separator and base64 encoded, then placed in the Authentication header after the word "Basic ".

---

Once an access_token is obtained from the oauth2 endpoint, it must be sent as a header for any actual API calls before expiring For details, see [the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/authentication/).

If you need a postman collection that already implements oauth token generation in pre-request scripts, see https://www.postman.com/paypal